# How can I look through two lists, find what matches, and pull associated strings out of one of them?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, printing, boolean

Say I have an address book filled with 30 addresses and no names associated with them. I want to find out who lives where, so I've also obtained the yellow pages which should have these addresses and the associated names of each resident.

Translate this into Python (3+), how can I find the names in the yellow pages and associate them with my 30 addresses into a new list that returns both the name and address?

I'm struggling to find the best way to think programmatically about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried variants of the following, but I am only getting one name associated with all the addresses, which I know is incorrect:

```
for name in yellowPages:
    for address in addressBook:
        if address == address in specificPage:
            print(name, "'s address is: " + address)
```

Update: Here's an example of a nested list I'm working with:

```
{
  "State": {
    "City": [
      {
        "County": {
          "name": "AAA",
          "address": "123 ABC",
          "zip_code": "111",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Right now I have:

```
phone_book = {'state': {'city': [{'county': {'name': 'AAA', 'address': 'ZZZ', 'zip_code': 'GGG', 'thing': 'EFG', 'chicken': 'CLUCK', 'alien': 'ET', 'car': 'BMW'}}, {'city': [{'county': {'name': 'BBB', 'address': 'YYY', 'zip_code': 'HHH', 'thing': 'TBH', 'chicken': 'CHICK', 'alien': 'BOB', 'car': 'LEXUS'}}, {'city': [{'county': {'name': 'CCC', 'address': 'XXX', 'zip_code': 'III', 'thing': 'POP', 'chicken': 'HEN', 'alien': 'GARY', 'car': 'TOYOTA'}}]}]}]}}

address_book = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'FFF', 'PPP', 'RRR']


for value in phone_book['state']['city']:
    for name in address_book:
        if value['county']['name'] == name:
            print("value['county']['address']: " + value['county']['address'])
            print("It's a match! name: " + name + " value['county']['name']: " + value['county']['name'])
            print("value['county']['zip_code']: " + value['county']['zip_code'])
            if value['county']['thing'] is None: 
                print("value['county']['thing']: None")
            else:
                print("value['county']['thing']: " + value['county']['thing'])
            if value['county']['chicken'] is None:
                print("value['county']['chicken']: None")
            else:
                print("value['county']['chicken']: " + value['county']['chicken'])
            if value['county']['alien'] is None:
                print("value['county']['alien']: null")
            else:
                print("value['county']['alien']: " + value['county']['alien'])
            print("value['county']['car']: " + value['county']['car'])
        else:
            print("value['county']['address']: " + value['county']['address'] + value['county']['name'] + " does't match anything")
```

And I'm getting the following output/errors:

```
value['county']['address']: ZZZ
It's a match! name: AAA value['county']['name']: AAA
value['county']['zip_code']: GGG
value['county']['thing']: EFG
value['county']['chicken']: CLUCK
value['county']['alien']: ET
value['county']['car']: BMW
value['county']['address']: ZZZAAA does't match anything
value['county']['address']: ZZZAAA does't match anything
value['county']['address']: ZZZAAA does't match anything
value['county']['address']: ZZZAAA does't match anything
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    if value['county']['name'] == name:
KeyError: 'county'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with your thinking. Maybe a simple example will help cement the approach you have begun to lay out:

I will replace "names" for simple letters, and "addresses" for simple numbers.

If you have your phone book in which names and addresses are associated:

`phone_book = [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5), ('g', 6), ('h', 7), ('i', 8), ('j', 9), ('k', 10), ('l', 11), ('m', 12)]`

and your address book which only contains addresses:
`address_book = [8, 5, 5, 5]`

Then iterating through the two lists like you laid out and printing the first element for each item in the phone book which matches an entry in your address book should provide all the missing names:

```
for address in address_book:
    for (letter,number) in phone_book:
        if address == number:
            print(letter + "'s address is: " + str(address))
```

This loop will print:

```
i's address is: 8
f's address is: 5
f's address is: 5
f's address is: 5
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! Is the concept the same if one of my list is nested further than the other? I'm continuing to fiddle with it, but running into a few different errors so far.

Comment: Essentially, yes! the main consideration is that as each of your lists become more nested, you need to incorporate more `for` loops to iterate through each subsequent nested loop. @jeng

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on your comment about additional nested lists:

Imagine that now your `phone_book` has sub lists that indicate different neighborhoods.

the code would look like this:

```
phone_book = [[('a', 0),('aa',10),('aaa',100)], [('b', 1),('bb',11),('bbb',111)], [('c', 2), ('cc', 22), ('ccc', 222)]]

address_book = [0, 11, 3, 22]

for address in address_book:
    for neighborhood in phone_book:
        for (letter,number) in neighborhood:
            if address == number:
                print(letter + "'s address is: " + str(address))
```

The additional for loop now allows you to scan each sublist and inspect each element individually (note `3` is in `address_book` but not `phone_book` so nothing is printed for it and the loop continues on to the next item in `address_book`.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helping but I think there's still a piece I'm still not quite understanding. I have a list that nests/sublists in about 4/5 steps. (Sorry, not quite sure how to explain this) but essentially, my result ends up being different "names" but they're all paired with the same "address". Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm, perhaps might have to do with the way your lists are structured. Any chance you can provide an example?

Comment: I updated the original post with an example. Thanks for taking a look!